# Python telegram bot - AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'data_filter'

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm coding a telegram bot in python for my association and I'm using a sqlite3 database. I would like to make sure that the words listed in this database are deleted by my bot. unfortunately I cannot make sure that all the words put in this db are considered as a list. Can you help me please ?

Here is my code in the main class:

```
def main():
updater = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)
conn = sqlite3.connect('list.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
mot = cur.execute("SELECT mot FROM list")
conn.commit()
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('test', censure))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('add', add))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(mot, censure))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You need to send more of your code, it's impossible to see where the error is, what function is the error occurring in?

Comment: When I run my bot I have this error in my console, it only appears when the variable "mot" is used.
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'data_filter'

Comment: if you want my full code you can see it here : https://pastebin.com/a0CEYQsA